# How to conditionally check a custom single post template in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, blogs, custom-post-type

I am using the following function to call a custom single post overriding the default one `single.php`

```
function call_different_single_post($single_template)
{
    global $post;

   $path =  get_stylesheet_directory() . '/includes/templates' . '/';
   $single_template = $path. 'single-1.php';
   return $single_template;
}

add_filter('single_template', 'call_different_single_post');
```

It's calling the `single-1.php` template for the single posts.

Now I want to check this template conditionally so that I can call some other js files like

```
function call_cust_js_single(){

    if( /*..this is single-1.php template..*/){
    wp_register_script('cust-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'custom.js', false, '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('cust-js');

    }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_cust_js_single');
```

Comment: are you showing any custom `post_type` in *single-1.php* file?

Comment: Try to use `is_singular( 'you_custom_post_type' );` -- refer -- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Comment: No it's not a custom post type nor for any custom post type. As you can see the file single-1.php is at the /includes/templates folder and from there I am calling this to override the default single.php file with this filter single_template. If I apply this, the default blog single.php is replaced with the single-1.php. But unsure how I can check this conditionally,

Comment: @htmlbrewery it does not work since single-1.php is not a custom post type which can be checked with is_singular() function.

Comment: Have you check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ ?

Comment: @NielsvanRenselaar is_page_template checks templates for pages, it's for single blog posts single.php. Is there any function or filter which I can use. I am also looking to add a body class to this template so that I can then use body class and apply other functions conditionally . So far no gain.

Comment: Are you trying to determine what post-template is being used and then if it's 'single-1.php' add a class to the body?

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, this will also do since I can then check the body_class and then call other files conditionally.

Comment: @Ayanize did the answer I posted help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a post similar to this but it doesn't quite cover your request. Here's the link [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file)

Here's the valuable code:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'var_template_include', 1000 );
function var_template_include( $t ){
    $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] = basename($t);
    return $t;
}

function get_current_template( $echo = false ) {
    if( !isset( $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'] ) )
        return false;
    if( $echo )
        echo $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
    else
        return $GLOBALS['current_theme_template'];
}
```

Now you have the function `get_current_template` that will return the filename of the template file.

Now edit your header.php file, here's an example:

```
<?php if('single-1.php' == get_current_template())
    {
        //load your scripts here
    } ?>
```

It's not as clean as what you were looking for but I think it will help you.